# ListVectorPlot on a section of a circle

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

Can anyone help, why ListVectorPlot and ListStreamPlot show vectors and streamlines lying outside the allowed domain? Here is my Mathematica code:

```
pp = Table[{r Cos[ϕ], r Sin[ϕ]}, {r, 0, 10, 
    0.5}, {ϕ, -π/6, π/6, 0.1}];
vv = Table[{{r Cos[ϕ], r Sin[ϕ]}, {1, 0}}, {r, 0, 10, 
    0.5}, {ϕ, -π/6, π/6, 0.1}];
GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[pp], ListVectorPlot[vv], ListStreamPlot[vv]}]
```

And I get the plots:

[image]

Why do the vectors in the second and third cases fill the whole square instead of the section of a circle?

Comment: Because `ListVectorPlot` performs interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
region = Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 10 && x != 0 && -π/6 < ArcTan[y/x] < π/6];

GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[pp], 
  ListVectorPlot[vv, RegionFunction -> region], 
  ListStreamPlot[vv, RegionFunction -> region]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I still do not understand, why Mathematica plotted vectors beyond the domain, and why one should to impose this domain again on the plot.